# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connections'

Tags: python, installation, connection, structure, pybrain

I am using pybrain library. When I import

```
from pybrain.structure import SigmoidLayer
```

I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connections'
```

I am quite confused about the installation of pybrain. I am using python 3.6 and windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install pybrain and which version of python are you using?

When i install it using pip3 and try

```
from pybrain.structure import SigmoidLayer
```

i get the same error as you, i then tried to install connections via pip3.
This fails with a syntax error in connections.

I then tried it with python2:

```
pip2 install pybrain connections scipy
```

this works.

So if you are using python2 you just need this:

```
pip install connections
```

Comment: I am using python 3.6.I used 'pip install pybrain' this command

Comment: https://github.com/operetta/connections/issues/1 seems to be a problem with the connections module. you can download it from github, make the changes in the issue and then install it manually with pip (or just put the files inside your project dir).